# Is there an ORM that can support Query Notifications?

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net, notifications

Is there an ORM out there which easily supports SQL's query notifications, so that when one client updates some data, other clients are alerted to the fact that their data is now outdated?

Ideally I'd like an ORM which manages object identity *itself* - that is - it refreshes already loaded objects as opposed to always creating new ones.

Does such a thing exist?

If not - could you recommend a pattern / technique for allowing clients to automatically detect data changes?